# RestSharp changes timezone on serialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, timezone, restsharp

RestSharp changes the timezone on my datetime-objects during serialization. The original datetime object is for example `2015-01-02 00:00:00` when I debug, but when RestSharp serializes it and I add it to my request using `request.AddBody(object)`, the payload has turned the date to `2015-01-01T22:00:00Z`. Therefore it has converted it back in time with 2 hours.

I'm currently in Sweden where it's GMT+2:00 so I'm guessing it's going to default GMT+0?

**Update**

I get a date in form of a `String` from the client, for example `"2015-01-02"`.
Then I try to parse it to a `DateTime`-object in the following code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldData) && DateTime.TryParse(fieldData, out dateTime)){ 
    budgetUtokad.SlutDatum = dateTime;
}
```

I need to specify the `Utc` in some kind of way here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `2015-01-02:00:00`? That's a very odd format, and it's unclear what it means. Can you provide a short but complete example of what's going on?

Comment: I've edited the question, so maybe now it's a little easier to understand.

Comment: A little bit - but your value of `2015-01-02 00:00:00` doesn't have any time zone, so it's sort of floating. That doesn't represent a specific point in time. It sounds like RestSharp is interpreting it as "that time in your local time zone" which isn't entirely unreasonable.

Comment: So, to make this work properly as I want, I would have to specify the timezone of the DateTime-object in some way?

Comment: Well it depends on what you're trying to achieve, basically. We still don't know what value you're *really* trying to represent.

Comment: I don't want the value to change at all. I want the original date to be the same (january 2:nd 2015) and not change depending on the hour-difference that is causing the change.

Comment: So you're not trying to represent a point in time at all? This is a problem with DateTime in general - it doesn't represent one particular thing. It sounds like you're not even trying to represent a date/time without a time zone, but simply a *date* (which would be 2015-01-02). But it looks like the default serializer in RestSharp does indeed convert to UTC. If you were happy with output of 2015-02-01T00:00:00Z that would be easy to achieve... would that be acceptable?

Comment: Absolutely, do you know if there's a way to configure the serializer in RestSharp to do that?

Comment: No, you should just create the `DateTime` value with a `Kind` of `Utc` to start with. Unfortunately we can't see any of the code where you're creating the `DateTime`, so we can't easily suggest an alternative.

Comment: I've updated my question now, maybe it's more easy to get a feel of what I'm trying to accomplish now?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're happy getting "midnight at the start of the given date, in UTC" you can use:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldData) && 
    DateTime.TryParseExact(
        fieldData,
        "yyyy-MM-dd",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,
        out dateTime)) { 
    budgetUtokad.SlutDatum = dateTime;
}
```

That's then in UTC already, so will be output by RestSharp as "2015-01-02T00:00:00Z".